# Perl script that will remotely ssh to linux and get memory status back to my machine

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, perl, memory-usage

I need help. I have Linux box (openSUSE 11.4); writing Perl script (Perl 5, version 12).
My script should SSH to the remote Linux machine and get back with the memory results. 
So far, I have SSH working with DSA private key for passwordless connection. 
Now I'm stuck with getting memory.

I tried to use Filesys::DiskSpace module, but I have some trouble while installing this module. Guess it will not work.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get Munin or Monit.

Answer (score 4):

Why bring perl into the mix? This is just a single-line deal:

```
$ ssh user@host free
```

Comment: I need Perl script. It's a project requirement. My script should be sort of automatic that will run on every linux machine and get memory statistics. and memory is only first part of the project... :)

Comment: Ahh, so this is a homework question. Well then looks like it'll get closed. Homework questions are off-topic.

Comment: it's not homework. I just want to automate my work rutine.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are dozens of open-source projects you can install that do this out of the box. Munin is one that I highly recommend. If you insist on a perl script, just make the above system call from within perl, storing the output in a variable.

Comment: After searching the Internet, I realized that I cannot use Munin on the network we have here. However, it is really great software! Thanks! Because we cannot install Munin-node to other devices in the network (such as Solaris and Windows based servers).

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions about any tool that I can use for network monitoring, which will be Perl based and will not require installing it to every machine on the network. Also for security reasons only SSH can be used for connection... I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just execute `cat /proc/meminfo` on the target machine to retrieve all informations about the current memory usage you could get from the system.

Comment: I was thinking about writing my script so that it will trigger a command on the other remote machine and get results back. But I have no idea how to write it.

Comment: use `Net::OpenSSH` to execute commands on the remote side, and simply parse `/proc/meminfo`, thats the easiest way you could go. Use `free` is another way, but its harder to parse. (just a little bit)

Comment: I also have Solaris servers on the network, so I need other specific command to get free memory available on the remote machine. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Maestro: check also `Net::OpenSSH::Parallel`